# How to verify the sorting of different columns using coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

In my application, I have to verify the sorting of the some columns(column names are used as hyperlink, for first time( when we click the column), it sorts the records in ascending order and 2nd time in descending order). 
I can record the sorting but how i can verify that sorting is correct. Is there any way or code to verify that sorting is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording and then replaying tests, the answer is no — the recorder is too stupid to do this on its own.

Solution is to write code: get data from the column to some collection, and then do all the tests you want on this data.